# Generic Method invocation

Tags: java, generics

I have this piece of code from "Java - A beginner's Guide - Schildt', Chapter 13:

```
package com.chapter.thirteen;

public class GenericMethodDemo {
static <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> boolean arraysEqual(T[] x, V[] y){
    if(x.length != y.length) return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        if(!x[i].equals(y[i])) return false;

    return true;
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    Integer [] nums  = { 1, 3, 3, 4, 6 };
    Integer [] nums2 = { 1, 3, 3, 4, 6 };
    Integer [] nums3 = { 1, 3, 3, 4, 6 };
    Integer [] nums4 = { 1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7};
    Double [] dVals = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};

    if(arraysEqual(nums, nums))
        System.out.println("nums equal nums");

    if(arraysEqual(nums, nums2))
        System.out.println("nums equal nums2");

    if(arraysEqual(nums, nums2))
        System.out.println("nums equal nums2");

    if(arraysEqual(nums, nums3))
        System.out.println("nums equal nums3");

    if(arraysEqual(nums, nums4))
        System.out.println("nums equal nums4");

    //Edit:Removed the comments from the below two lines.

    if(arraysEqual(nums, dVals))
        System.out.println("Nums equal dVals");

    }
}
```

The compilation fails with the message - 
`"Error:(39, 12) java: method arraysEqual in class com.chapter.thirteen.GenericMethodDemo cannot be applied to given types; required: T[],V[] found: java.lang.Integer[],java.lang.Double[]  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds equality constraints: java.lang.Integer lower bounds: V,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Integer"`,
 which is expected.

However, when I missed adding the parameter to Comparable (as shown in the code below), the code compiles and produces the correct result.

```
package com.chapter.thirteen;


public class GenericMethodDemo {
    static <T extends Comparable, V extends T> boolean arraysEqual(T[] x, V[] y){
    if(x.length != y.length) return false;

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        if(!x[i].equals(y[i])) return false;

    return true;
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    Integer [] nums  = { 1, 3, 3, 4, 6 };
    Integer [] nums2 = { 1, 3, 3, 4, 6 };
    Integer [] nums3 = { 1, 3, 3, 4, 6 };
    Integer [] nums4 = { 1, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7};
    Double [] dVals = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4};

    if(arraysEqual(nums, nums))
        System.out.println("nums equal nums");

    if(arraysEqual(nums, nums2))
        System.out.println("nums equal nums2");

    if(arraysEqual(nums, nums2))
        System.out.println("nums equal nums2");

    if(arraysEqual(nums, nums3))
        System.out.println("nums equal nums3");

    if(arraysEqual(nums, nums4))
        System.out.println("nums equal nums4");

    if(arraysEqual(nums, dVals))
        System.out.println("Nums equal dVals");
   }
}
```

Can someone please explain why the compilation does not fail in the second instance? I had expected the compiler to complain about **T extends Comparable, V extends T** in the second instance?

What's going on?

Comment: Your first code compiles also. Which java version are you using?

Comment: When you remove the type parameter from `Comparable`, you are starting to use raw types and the story becomes completely different. Raw types exist only for compatibility with the pre-Java-5 code and should not be used in new code which does not need such compatibility. You should not try to understand when raw types work and when not, you should instead forget about them.

Comment: Hi, I'm using java version 1.8.0_65 on IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5 Community Edition. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because of the rules of [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2775450).

When you do,

```
static <T extends Comparable, V extends T> boolean arraysEqual(T[] x, V[] y)
```

You are basically stating, both T and V are subtype of `Comparable`.
Which means calling `arraysEqual(Integer[], Double[])` should work because both `Integer` and `Double` implement `Comparable`.

But when you add generic type to `Comparable`, the contract is lost,

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>, V extends T> boolean arraysEqual(T[] x, V[] y)
```

In this, `Double` is not implementing `Comparable<Integer>`, which is why the compiler error.

**EDIT:** If your question is why the rawtype `Comparable` is not giving compiler error, the answer is that's how generics work...

You can try with `Number` too,

```
static <T extends Number, V extends T> boolean arraysEqual(T[] x, V[] y)
```

No **rawtypes** are involved in this, and you can call `arrayEquals(Integer[], Double[])` to this and it will work fine because both are `Number`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I haven't read up on "Raw Types" yet. The section on "Raw Types and Legacy Code" comes up next in the chapter. I had just mis-typed the function invocation and expected the compilation to fail. It baffled me when it didn't! Thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The method `arraysEqual` is declared to recive type `V` that has `T` as supertype. In other words `V` must implement or extend `T`. This is not case with `java.lang.Double`(`V`) and `java.lang.Integer` (`T`), and therefore constitutes a compile error.

*Edited to add*
If you remove parameterization from `Comparable` (declare it as `Comparable` not `Comparable<T>`) compiler sees the `T` as `Comparable`, not as `Comparable<Integer>`, and then `V` is seen as `V extends Comparable` which `java.lang.Double` is.

Comment: The question is not why the first code produces error, but why the second code compiles.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it succeeds with a raw `Comparable` is actually due to the improved type inference in Java 8.

If you try to compile it with Java 7 javac, you get:

```
            if(arraysEqual(nums, dVals))
               ^
  required: T[],V[]
  found: Integer[],Double[]
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: Double
    bound(s): Integer
  where T,V are type-variables:
    T extends Comparable declared in method arraysEqual(T[],V[])
    V extends T declared in method arraysEqual(T[],V[])
```

However, Java 8 is trying to find a proper set of types that successfully fulfills the constraints. Instead of insisting that the arrays are types `Integer[]` and `Double[]`, it infers them as `Comparable[]` and `Double[]`. `Double` is declared to implement `Comparable<Double>` which means that it implements the raw `Comparable`.

This cannot work when the generic type is properly used, as `Integer` implement `Comparable<Integer>`, not raw `Comparable`, and `Double` does not implement that.

This example in the book seems to be a bit contrived, as you are not actually using `compareTo` in the method. You would have run into the same issue if you had removed the constraint on `T` completely:

```
static <T, V extends T> boolean arraysEqual(T[] x, V[] y){...}
```

This would not have compiled in Java 7 for `Integer[]` and `Double[]`, as `Double` does not extend `Integer`. But in Java 8 it compiles, because it infers the type `Number & Comparable<?>` for `T` and `Double` extends that. `Number & Comparable<?>` is the result of Java 8 trying to find the most strict common type, so that you'll be able to assign T to a variable of type `Number` or `Comparable<?>` without explicit cast.

Comment: A small correction, when you remove the constraint on T, it would be inferred as `Object` by default not `Number`.

Comment: @Codebender actually, it infers `Number & Comparable<?>` as the type, not `Object`.